# Is there a more colloquial way of saying “vegan” than “纯素食者”?

Tags: colloquialisms

Like a more laypersons way of understanding what veganism means. Kinda like "我吃素的" as a vegetarian.

Comment: You could just say 纯素 or 素食. 我吃素 (without 的) is also fine.

Comment: question reminds some users of police on 天安门  using Segway PTs  电动平衡车、自平衡电瓶车、平衡车 for short  https://wheelive.com/cn/archives/5122  for personal transportation (in fact 做巡逻车), is there a 口语 name different from e.g. 平衡车 for these?

Answer (score 2):

in cantonese, you may say 食全齋, sound files:  [食](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/sik6.Mp3) 
 [全](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/cyun4.Mp3) 
 [齋](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zaai1.Mp3)

or, colloquially, say 吃全素, in mandarin.

Answer (score 1):

try "素食者"

If you chose to say"我吃素的"， you should be careful. Because "吃素的" sometimes has a deeper mearning in oral language - Incapacitated, bullied, weak.

Comment: re：oral language， 现代汉语词典 simply gives these 2 meanings w/o characterizing either as 口语，although their example seems to have 口语 flavour：＂现代汉语词典＂：吃素（１）不吃鱼、肉等食物。佛教徒的吃素戒律还包括不吃葱蒜等（２）比喻不事杀伤（多用于否定式)：你敢搞乱？告诉你，我的拳头可不是～的。

Comment: The second one. 我的拳头可不‌​是吃素的 means 'I am a strong person, I can beat you up, don't even try to fool me'

Comment: more at bkrs：比喻不厉害; 好惹。他可不是吃素的 He’s not easy to deal with.

Comment: 素食者 means vegetarian, not vegan, but the note about the connotations of 吃素的 is good.

Answer (score -1):

我是素食主義者。Might be a better choice, it also means, "I am a vegetarian".